# I have a timestamp and I want to add 100 miliseconds to it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, timestamp, type-conversion

this is a python / pandas data type question.

So lets say I have a timestamp, which is in STRING format:
1675242910384942479

I would like to know the timestamp + 100 milliseconds.

Ideally I would like a function take takes in N (number of miliseconds) and timestamp and returns timestamp + N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your timestamp is in nanoseconds, you need to add the milliseconds multiplied by 1,000,000

```
def add_ms(timestamp, ms):
    return int(timestamp) + 1000000 * ms
```